# Multivariable calculus problem contest

Tags: functions, multivariable-calculus, contest-math, functional-equations

Let $a_1,b_1,c_1,a_2,b_2,c_2$ be positive real numbers. And $F,G:(0,\infty)\times (0, \infty) \to(0,\infty)$, differentiable and positive functions that satisfies: 
$$\frac{x}{F} = 1 + a_1x+ b_1y + c_1G$$

$$\frac{y}{G} = 1 + a_2x+ b_2y + c_2F.$$
Prove that if $0 < x_1 \le x_2$, and $0< y_2 \le y_1 $, then $F(x_1, y_1) \le F(x_2, y_2)$, and $G(x_1, y_1) \ge G(x_2, y_2)$.

Comment: I haven't try to much. Of course not, it is from an Iberoamerican math competition from 2013.

Comment: Thanks for responding on that (people do post questions from ongoing contests way too frequently, and it's a pain to weed them out). If you have tried anything, please put it (at least describe it) in your question; if not, we probably shouldn't spoil the question for you.

Comment: It would be nice if someone posts a hint. I think the things I have tried aren't useful at all.

Comment: It's still good to post what you have tried - it shows that you have spent time on the problem and people might be able to point you in a direction based on what you did.